# How to effectively capture traffic on port 5060 between specific time internals?

Tags: networking, tcpdump, wireshark, sip, tshark

users.

I want to capture traffic on port 5060 for one week in a file, than wants wireshark to rotate file and start capturing for next week with a different file name.

I know little about tshark, dumpcap but wants to know, what is more effective way to achieve this and how. As file will contain data of almost one week.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
dumpcap -b files:52 -b duration:"$((7*24*60*60))" -i any -f 'port 5060' -w cap
```

Would make one file per week, keeping only 52 stored in files named like `cap_00001_20150403173051`.